# Dagger and AndroidAnnotations - how to inject @Pref, @Bean, etc?

Tags: android, android-annotations, dagger

I'm using [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) in my project and just hooked [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) + [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) + Espresso in.

Currently I have an Activity with [SharedPrefences](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/SharedPreferencesHelpers) and a [class](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance%20custom%20classes) 'injected' by AndroidAnnotations.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
  @Pref Prefs_ prefs;
  @Bean SomeManager mManager;
}
```

Now if I want to use a Dagger to inject these two, what my `@Provide` methods should look like?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@Provide` methods should call the `getInstance_` method of generated bean classes. This methods creates a new instance and injects the necessary objects. For the generated preference, you should call the constructor `new Prefs_(context)`. However, this is not a too clean way since these generated methods are supposed to called by AA. Also `Dagger` integration is only working in the snapshot release, check out [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/pull/982) thread. But as you can see, you can use `Dagger` now, but it is not convenient, and it seems to be better to just use AA injection for the AA generated classes for now.